# exceptions.TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: scrapy

I have a file ccbank_spider.py, below are the content

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):

 #some code

 #for hitting and parsing of the Account URL
 for accountURL in (strip(s) for itemArr in items for s in itemArr['accountURL']):
    print accountURL
    yield request(accountURL, callback=self.account_transactions)

 def account_transactions(self, response):
  print 'print text'
  return None
```

i get the below error

```
          File "D:\NextGen\workspace\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\ccbank_spider.py", line       45, in after_login
       yield request(accountURL, callback=self.account_transactions)
   exceptions.TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          File "D:\NextGen\workspace\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\ccbank_spider.py", line       45, in after_login
       yield request(accountURL, callback=self.account_transactions)
   exceptions.TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It should be `Request` not `request`, having that you did `from scrapy.http import Request`